# auto update all nested class/model property in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am wondering whether there's a way to construct a nested model, in which the value of a field of the main model is automatically passed to a designated field of its nested model.

For example, if I have a `Factory` view model and a `Machine` view model:

```
public class Factory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool HasPower { get; set; }

    public List<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public bool HasPower { get; set; }
}
```

The `Factory` contains a list of `Machine`. I would like to have the `HasPower` value in each `Machine` always set by the `HasPower` value in `Factory`. Or maybe the `HasPower` property in each `Machine` is just a pointer point to the `HasPower` value in `Factory`.

I have no idea whether this is achievable or not. And googling doesn't give me any useful result.

Comment: When you initialize your factory class and set the Machines list property, just set the value of each machine to that of the Factory.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine getter/setter of your HasPower property on Factory class as follows :

```
public bool HasPower
{
    get => Machines?.First().HasPower ?? false;
    set
    {
      foreach(var machine in Machines)
           machine.HasPower = value;
    }

}
```

Also, you can mark your HasPower property with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] if Factory class is a Enity Framework POCO so that it is always computed.

Comment: Thank you! This seems working! I didn't realize it can be done with `get` and `set` for the `HasPower` property before. Much appreciated.